# getting/optimizing counts with various conditions and tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return counts for different conditions and tables in one call.  I previously had each one of these in its own subquery, but realized there was no point in querying the `realtime_logs` table 4 times... so I changed it to the stmt below which works as expected.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        sum(case when event_title = 'opened' then 1 end) as opened, 
        sum(case when event_title = 'closed' then 1 end) as closed,
        sum(case when event_title = 'viewed' then 1 end) as viewed,
        sum(case when event_title LIKE '%blocked%' then 1 end) as blocked 
    FROM realtime_logs
");
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Doing this though I lost the ability to get counts from other tables though... I want something like this...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("
        SELECT
            sum(case when event_title = 'opened' then 1 end) as opened, 
            sum(case when event_title = 'closed' then 1 end) as closed,
            sum(case when event_title = 'viewed' then 1 end) as viewed,
            sum(case when event_title LIKE '%blocked%' then 1 end) as blocked 
        FROM realtime_logs

       // I also want to return the count for this different table

       (SELECT COUNT(location_id)
        FROM spc_location_logs
       ) as locations
");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you simply split into two statement/queries? You can use PHP after to merge returned values into one array. Try this:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        sum(case when event_title = 'opened' then 1 end) as opened, 
        sum(case when event_title = 'closed' then 1 end) as closed,
        sum(case when event_title = 'viewed' then 1 end) as viewed,
        sum(case when event_title LIKE '%blocked%' then 1 end) as blocked,
    FROM realtime_logs
");

$stmt2 = $db->prepare('
    SELECT COUNT(location_id) AS locations
    FROM spc_location_logs
');

$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();

$arr1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$arr2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);

$arr  = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Note im Using `FETCH_KEY_PAIR` mode.

Comment: Of course I could, but I am trying to optimize these and lower the number of times the db is hit... there will be another 10+ tables I want to get counts for in addition to the one extra I listed.  There will also be bindings (was just trying to simplify the post without additional params).

Comment: Its better to do multiple queries then do sub-queries and have one giant query. Will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

One is to put the second count query as a subquery in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT SUM(event_title = 'opened') AS opened,
       SUM(event_title = 'closed') AS closed,
       SUM(event_title = 'viewed') AS viewed,
       SUM(event_title LIKE '%blocked%') AS blocked,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) from spc_location_logs) AS locations
FROM realtime_logs
```

The second is with a join:

```
SELECT SUM(r.event_title = 'opened') AS opened,
       SUM(r.event_title = 'closed') AS closed,
       SUM(r.event_title = 'viewed') AS viewed,
       SUM(r.event_title LIKE '%blocked%') AS blocked,
       l.locations
FROM realtime_logs AS r
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS locations
     FROM spc_location_logs) AS l
```

This second method is a bit more flexible -- you could have multiple counts in the second query and display them all.

BTW, you should usually use `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(column_name)`, unless the column may contain null values and you need to not count them.

Comment: Thanks - this is more what I was thinking.  I always thought specifying one column rather than * would be quicker?  Also, I notice everyone always uses aliases on everything... what is the benefit of aliasing `realtime_logs` for example rather than just explicitly using it in each case... `realtime_logs.event_title, etc...